# Return duplicates

Tags: java, mysql

I tried to insert my data into my database using this code but I kept on getting duplicates and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I am very new at Java and MySQL so any help or guidance are very much appreciated.

Below are my codes

```
ApproveButton = new JButton("Approve");
        ApproveButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        ApproveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            

            try{

                int rows=table.getRowCount();
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/swing_demo", "root123", "root12345");
                
             PreparedStatement upd = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO approvedsales(productname, quantity, price, total, date) VALUES (?, ?,?,?,? )");

                
                for(int row = 0; row<rows; row++)
                {
                    String productname = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    String quantity = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                    String price = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 2);
                    String total = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 3);
                    String date = (String)table.getValueAt(row, 4);
                    upd.setString(1, productname);
                    upd.setString(2, quantity);
                    upd.setString(3, price);
                    upd.setString(4, total);
                    upd.setString(5, date);

                    upd.addBatch();
                }
                upd.executeBatch();
                int x = upd.executeUpdate();
                if (x == 0) {
                    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ApproveButton, "This is alredy exist");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ApproveButton,
                    "Data are successfully stored");
            }}
                catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
        }});
        ApproveButton.setBounds(129, 204, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(ApproveButton);
```

My table in database, all of the columns are varchar(255), no unique and primary keys

```
productname  quantity  price  total  date
biscuits        1       1      1      7th Sept 2020
```

Comment: Please show your DB schema too, and explain what you mean by 'getting duplicates'.

Comment: @tgdavies edited my question. Getting duplicates mean, everytime I clicked the button Approve, the data will be inserted to my table but with duplicates

Comment: @Andreas there is no error, just duplicates in my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use [Statement#executeBatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()), not executeUpdate.

```
int[] xs = upd.executeBatch();
if (IntStream.of(xs).min().orElse(1) == 0) { ...
```

By also doing an executeUpdate the SQL is executed twice.

Of course a PRIMARY KEY in the table's column definition for product would have been nice.

Furthermore MySQL can combine INSERT with an UPDATE alternative, REPLACE is - I believe - the name.

Comment: I got error of Incompatible operand types

Comment: The SQL is executed many times. To clarify, *"the SQL is executed twice"* actually means that the *last set of values* used with the SQL is used *again*.

Comment: @strawberrylatte forgot that `min()` delivers an OptionalInt. Was intended to check whether a 0 was for some record update returned.

Comment: About what @Andreas says: a `PreparedStatement` (without calling `clearParameters`) can be executed again. Here batch execution and normal update execution. Not sure what happens, but it would explain the duplicate insertion. Other explanations could exist too.

Comment: @JoopEggen What happens is `executeBatch()` executes the `INSERT` statement N times with the sets of values added to the batch. It then clears the batch, but not the parameters. When `executeUpdate()` is then called, the `INSERT` statement is executes directly (unbatched), it reuses the same parameter values that the last statement in the batch used, causing a duplicate insert for the last inserted row.

Comment: @Andreas so only the last record was duplicated? Which would be logical.